# Mqtt - How to differentiate a will and testament message from a regular message

Tags: mqtt

I am using 'paho' client and 'mosquitto' broker.

How do we differentiate between a 'regular' and a 'will' message received. Basically I need to filter out and take a different action on receiving a will message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, you don't. They are just normal messages.

If you need to know they are different either include something in the message payload to differentiate or publish to a different topic.